# Getting notified of any action taken by user on windows

Tags: windows

I am laying out a concept for an app and in it,i need the administrator to get notified of any action a user takes like starting a program,opening a folder,renaming a file,deleting files,opening files etc.

The concept i am thinking of is like jquery events

```
$('.class_here').click(function(){
alert('some one clicked the start button');
});
```

but this is on windows.I have looked at the documentation for windows event viewer and event logs but i would like more direction if this sort of thing is available on windows.

Thanks.

Comment: Windows has a full auditing infrastructure built in. It can probably fulfill your needs but it has a high performance overhead - so it's not turned on for everything by default. Turning it on is more of an administrative task than a programming one.

Comment: Supposing i want to do something once the user clicks the start button,is there a way to do that in c# or java without turning on the entire auditing infrastructure?.