# Can windows eventtriggers be used for trivial events?

Tags: c#, windows, event-triggers

In an application I am making, I want to know when a user copies a file or clicks the start button. Those actions would be considered too trivial but they carry some importance in my application.

Yesterday, I received a comment [Getting notified of any action taken by user on windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21085260/getting-notified-of-any-action-taken-by-user-on-windows#comment31715811_21085260) on a similar question so I am hesitating to switch the entire auditing infrastructure.

Going as per explanation of eventtriggers http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490901.aspx

> Creates a new event trigger that monitors and acts upon the occurrence
>   of log events of given criteria.

I am not sure what the limits of eventtriggers and how it can help me achieve my goal without so much overhead. Can eventtriggers help me set a trigger that notifies me when the start button is clicked?.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Not possible, to my knowledge, unless you poll to find out the status. This example was already brought up in a previous question on SO:
[How can I detect when the Windows 7 start menu opens](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11120514/how-can-i-detect-when-the-windows-7-start-menu-opens)

Theoretically you could write something that lives on a different thread that queries the start menu at given intervals. Then, if the start menu was detected as open you could trigger the code you want done. Just a thought...